# How to get all events on a day drupal full calendar?

Tags: jquery, drupal, fullcalendar

My question is regarding Full calendar module.Which i am using for event creation in my site.Can anyone tell me how can i get and show (in a drupal view ) all events  of a particular day,when it is clicked. I mean i want to get and show all events on dayClick event.

Thanks in advance.

Tapu

Answer (score 0):

Use calendar block. It does exact same thing.